# Find out the top 3 customers by sum of sales from different groups for the last 30 days - Amazon interview

Tags: sql, sql-server

This was my Amazon SQL interview question which I bombed miserably.

We have 3 tables:

```
customers    orders       catalog
cust_id      order_date   catalog_id
cust_name    order_id     catalog_name
             unit_price   cust_id
             quantity
             catalog_id
```

The output expected was to find top 3 customers from the 3 catalog / business units for the last 30 days. I tried partitioning over total sales but the last 30 day sales and multiple joins threw me off. Following were the columns requested:

```
cust_id   cust_name  catalog_name  total_sales(unit_price*quantity)
1         David      Books         1400
2         John       Books         1200
3         Lisa       Books         1000
4         Paul       DVDs          500
2         John       DVDs          313.5
5         James      DVDs          220
6         Alice      TV            110
1         David      TV            87.5
7         Jerry      TV            56
```

I understand basic 'partitioning over order by' however I have not used it over multiple tables with a datestamp. Kindly help me in understanding this concept. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post your attempted query?

Comment: Basically - you use `row_number() over (partition by... order by...)` in a cte and select where rn <= 3. Nothing fancy. Or even better - top 3 with ties.

Comment: I understand the row_number() over partition, can you please expand on the last 30 day sale as well?

Answer (score 0):

The query below should give you an idea.

```
select * 
from (select c.cust_id,c.cust_name,ct.catalog_name,sum(o.unit_price * o.quantity) as total_sales, 
     ,dense_rank() over(partition by ct.catalog_name order by sum(o.unit_price * o.quantity) desc) as rnk
      from customers c
      join orders o on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
      join catalog ct on ct.catalog_id = o.catalog_id     
      --last 30 days filter
      where o.order_date >= date_add(day,-30,cast(getdate() as date)) and o.order_date < cast(getdate() as date)
      group by c.cust_id,c.cust_name,ct.catalog_name
     ) t 
where rnk <= 3
```

Comment: Thank you Vamsi!
Can you please explain why we use Group By c.cust_id,c.cust_name,ct.catalog_name instead of 
Grouping Sets?